# Angular 2 add multiple classes via [class.className] binding

Tags: javascript, angular, binding

While adding a single class works great in this way -

`[class.loading-state]="loading"`

But how do I add multiple classes
Ex if `loading` is `true` add class - `"loading-state" & "my-class"`

How do I get it done via the `[class] binding`

Answer (score 100, accepted):

You can do this by simply using `ngClass` :

Here first,second and third are the name of the classes.

And instead of true/false , you can directly put your conditions over there

```
 <div [ngClass]="{'first': true, 'second': true, 'third': false}">...</div>
```

In your case

```
 <div [ngClass]="{'loading-state': loading, 'my-class': loading }">...</div>
```

Or Shorter Veriosn (as @matko.kvesic commented)

```
<div [ngClass]="{'loading-state my-class': loading}">...</div>
```

Comment: Or even: [ngClass]="{'loading-state my-class': loading}"

Comment: Testing with Angular 7 (and above ) you are now able to use [class] as you would use [ngClass] with multiple classes e.g.

[class]="['my-first-class', 'my-second-class']"

See below for simple example for <p> tag
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-playground-inhqyx?file=app/hello-framework/hello-framework.component.html

Comment: @matko.kvesic this doesn't work anymore nowadays  -> `The token provided ('classA classB') contains HTML space characters, which are not valid in tokens.`

Comment: I still believe this does not answer the initial question. How can multiple classes be added using class binding (not ngClass)?

Answer (score 12):

Although [Vivek Doshi](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43180464/2260948) answer is totally correct, below I put other alternatives to do the same with different boolean variables:

### 1st Solution: [class.className]

#### Template:

```
<div [class.first-class]="addFirst" [class.second-class]="addSecond">...</div>
```

#### Component:

```
export class MyComponent {
  ...
  addFirst: boolean;
  addSecond: boolean;
  ...
}
```

### 2nd Solution: [ngClass] with method binding

#### Template:

```
<div [ngClass]="setClasses()">...</div>
```

#### Component:

```
export class MyComponent {
  ...
  addFirst: boolean;
  addSecond: boolean;
  ...
  setClasses() {
    return {
      'first-class': this.addFirst,
      'second-class': this.addSecond
    };
  }
  ...
}
```

### Last solution, but not least:

#### Template:

```
<div [ngClass]="{'first-class': addFirst, 'second-class': addSecond}">...</div>
```

#### Component:

```
export class MyComponent {
  ...
  addFirst: boolean;
  addSecond: boolean;
  ...
}
```