# Can I dynamically set the css class to the return value of a typescript function?

Tags: javascript, html, css, class, typescript

I want to determine the css class based of the return value of a function call like the following:

```
<ion-col style="getBooking(950)">
   <div (tap)="this.makeOrRemoveBooking(950)">09:30</div>
</ion-col>
<ion-col style="this.getBooking(1000)">
    <div (tap)="this.makeOrRemoveBooking(950)">10:00</div>
</ion-col>
<ion-col style="this.getBooking(1050)">
    <div (tap)="this.makeOrRemoveBooking(950)">10:30</div>
</ion-col>
```

Here is the function:

```
    getBooking(time: number) {
    for (const book of this.localListOfBookings) {
        if (book.startTime <= time && time < book.endTime) {
            if (book.bookedByName == this.currentUserName) {
                return "yourRoom"
            } else {
                return "available"
            }
            // return book.bookedByName
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: How about using ngclass? And set the property value inside the function? Can you post the function body where you are returning the value

Comment: Just added it to the question

Comment: Please check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43180436/angular-2-add-multiple-classes-via-class-classname-binding/43180464#43180464