# Set different colors each row index in html table using Angular 4

Tags: angular, typescript

I would like to set different colors for selected rows programatically each time when a button outside the table is clicked. I am using the latest version of angular.

I know how to set row color with css but do not know how to influence the css class programatically in typescript.

```
.ui-table .ui-table-tbody > tr:nth-child(1) {
    background-color: #2DA449; 
}
```

Is there some way to edit the css class to set the child index and b-color in typescript?

Comment: Look at my answer here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47433827/angular-4-change-color-dependent-on-value/47433988#47433988 might help

Comment: You must look Ngclass at https://angular.io/api/common/NgClass

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Typescript

```
export class MyComponent{
    items:any[];
    changeColors(){
    // I'm just selecting the first row for this example but you have to define your own logic 
    this.items[0].color ="#ddd";
    }
}
```

HTML

```
<button (click)="changeColors()">Change colors<button/>
<table>
  <tr *ngFor="let item in items;let i=index" [style.color]="item.color">
    ...
  </tr>
</table>
```

More documention can be found https://angular.io/guide/template-syntax#binding-targets

Comment: Good example but how to set the color in the chsngeColors() method instead giving the tr tag a static one?

Comment: Ah i misunderstood your question, just update my answer.

Answer (score 1):

All you need is [`ngClass`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43180464/2349407) :

```
<td [ngClass]="{'selected': checkSelected(i)}"> // checkSelected should return boolean
```

[**WORKING DEMO**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-td-selected)