# Bootstrap col-sm-4 not added to div

Tags: angular

I am using the below code. I am using Angular 12.

```
<div class="container">
 <div class="row">
   <div  [class.col-sm-4]="true">     </div>
</div>
</div>
```

When I see the UI, I am not getting col-Sm-4 class attribute there for div.
what can be the reason for it ? and how to overcome from it. ?

Comment: You can simply use ngClass, see => https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43180436/angular-2-add-multiple-classes-via-class-classname-binding

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use ngClass for this.
For example:

```
[ngClass]="yourConditionHere == true? 'col-sm-4': '' "
```